# Export settings question from Beamer example written by org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

A minimal example can be found in [Here](http://orgmode.org/manual/A-Beamer-Example.html#A-Beamer-Example)

Can anyone explain the following line funtion?

```
#+COLUMNS: %45ITEM %10BEAMER_ENV(Env) %10BEAMER_ACT(Act) %4BEAMER_COL(Col) %8BEAMER_OPT(Opt)
```

The [worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/presentation.org.html) says

> ## for a column view of options and configurations for the individual frames

But a sentence can't make me understand.
To do a test, I change the number in it but finding the output frame doesn't change.

Comment: Have you read http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-view.html#Column-view?

Comment: @JeanPierre, Thank you for showing me the way. Now I know it.